# Twitter Bootstrap 3 SideBar Notification not displaying properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a web page whereby I want content to display at the left side(9 columns) and Ads to display at the right sidebar(3 columns) .At the left side I have nested two rows and want content t0 be displayed inside the rows. But when I test on a live server the Ads dont display properly. I am using Bootstrap 3 to partition the page.

```
<!--Parent row -->
<div class="row">  

    <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
             //Page content.....
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
             //Page content.....
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
             //...Google Ads display
        </div>
    </div>

</div> <!--END parent row -->
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap, all the columns must add up to 12. I can see that you've got 3 sets of 9 columns which makes 18.

The layout would need to be as so:

```
<!--Parent row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><!-- Nested col 1 (of 50%) --></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><!-- Nested col 2 (of 50%) --></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><!-- ...Google Ads display --></div>
</div> <!--END parent row -->
```

This will put the Google Ads column to the right, and have two nested columns inside the Page content columns.

The `.row` class should be used only once per row, not per column.